# How to compress a YUYV image into a jpeg

Tags: c, jpeg, color-space, libjpeg-turbo, turbojpeg

(Cross posted to libjpeg-turbo-users list.)

I'm having a problem with libjpeg-turbo.

The tjCompress2 function requires an RGB or Greyscale image to compress.

```
http://libjpeg-turbo.sourceforge.net/ljtdoc.branches_1.3.x/turbojpeg-c/group___turbo_j_p_e_g.html#gaba62b7a98f960839b588579898495cf2
```

(Sorry, you'll have to paste that link as it breaks markdown.)

My webcam (a PS3 EyeToy) has the following characteristics:

```
chris@raspberrypi ~ $ v4l2-ctl --get-fmt-video
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height  : 320/240
    Pixel Format  : 'YUYV'
    Field         : None
    Bytes per Line: 640
    Size Image    : 153600
    Colorspace    : SRGB
```

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Color_space_transformation it looks like YUYV is equivalent to the YCbCr that JPEG needs (though it has half the Cb and Cr data, compared with luminance).  Have I understood correctly?

I know how to turn YUYV into RGB, using a matrix, but it seems a waste of scarce CPU cycles and colour accuracy, to perform two colour space changes when none are needed.

Is there a function which can directly compress a YUYV image into a JPEG?

Answer (score 2):

Since the time the question was asked, a [`tjCompressFromYUV`](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/libjpeg-turbo/code/trunk/doc/html/group___turbo_j_p_e_g.html#ga0b931126c7a615ddc3bbd0cca6698d67) function has been implemented in the TurboJPEG API. It takes an image in the `YCbCr` or `YUV` format and transforms it into a JPEG image.

However, to compress a `YUYV` image using the TurboJPEG API you'd still need to transform the `YUYV` into a `Y-Cb-Cr`pixel format.

There might also be a little chance to use the `YUYV` image as `YUV` image with a *subsampling of `4:2:2`*, as this would result in two `Y` components per `UV` components, but if [this source](http://d1.ourdev.cn/bbs_upload782111/files_35/ourdev_610572SSB6C7.txt) is exact, there are four different possible ways to place the `YUVY` components. But to be positive, there is a chance of 1/4 for this to work.

Otherwise you might also transform the image using [PNGU](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/PNGU) or something similar before you transform it to JPEG, as this library is able to "save YCbYCr images in png RGB8 format."